# "Add to Homescreen" Banner in Rails PWA

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, web-applications, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I've made a small PWA in RoR; following and I followed [Google's guide](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/app-install-banners/) on having "Add to Homescreen" banners. Everything in devtools is fine: the service worker is registered, the manifest.json is found, the "Add to Homescreen" link is displayed and runs in the tool drawer.

I even installed Lighthouse like they said and ran the report; it says everything should work. However, I have yet to see the banner (yes, it isn't already on my homescreen; yes, I visited at least five minutes apart).

Does anyone have an idea on what the threshold is WRT users activity to make the banner appear?

(ps. does anyone want to try it out [here](https://diogn.es)?)

Answer (score 2):

There's actually a google chrome flag for bypassing those engagement checks, it's called "Bypass user engagement checks".

So you'll need to go to chrome://flags, then find that flag, enable it, and then restart chrome.

The banner should show up every time once that flag is enabled, assuming everything is in line with your manifest.json and service worker.

Answer (score 0):

I saw you referenced two manifests on your page:

Line 20:

```
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />
```

Line 27:

```
<link rel="manifest" href="/assets/favicon/manifest-71676a3789f8b2a25498b2271ddc3288b14553d94e25c37030e6d69d46d72b81.json" />
```

When I frist load the page I see the mainfest definition in chrome dev tools, but when I reload the page the manifest is gone.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the responses; I waited like a day, cleared my caches completely, and got the banner. I still don't know the threshold for how many times you have to visit, but at least it works.